# Laravel using action in href vs routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am having to work with code someone else wrote. I see they use the following syntax:

```
<a href="{{ action('MessagesController@index') }}">Messages</a>
```

Whereas I would have used :

```
<a href="messages">Messages</a>
```

and catered for that in routes.php

I am not sure why the "action" syntax is used - is it from an older version of Laravel perhaps?

I am using Laravel 5.3 currently

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `action` helper function is a function that generates a URL to the given action. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-action

It has been available since Laravel 5.1 (or roundabouts)

Comment: Thanks! - Is there any preference as to which format to use - they seem to do the same/similar thing?

Comment: I tend to use the `route()` helper function in my projects, I suppose the `action()` helper takes out the need for named routes, but I'm not too sure what the exact use case would be :)

Comment: My suggestion is to always use named routes - much easier to maintain.